# I want to store langitude and latitude of adress given by user i done all my configurations but did not understand why this error happen help me?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, postgis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyVqW.png)

windows
I want to store langitude and latitude of adress given by user i done all my configurations but did not understand why this error happen help me?
my settings.py file

```
VIRTUAL_ENV_BASE = os.environ.get('VIRTUAL_ENV')
print(VIRTUAL_ENV_BASE)

GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = VIRTUAL_ENV_BASE + '/Lib/site-packages/osgeo/geos_c.dll'
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = VIRTUAL_ENV_BASE + '/Lib/site-packages/osgeo/gdal304.dll'
```

My model.py file

```
`from datetime import *
import geocoder
import os
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gismodels
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    salary = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    positions = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    point = gismodels.PointField(default=Point(0.0,0.0))
    last_date = models.DateTimeField(default=return_Date_time)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        g = geocoder.mapquest(self.address, key=os.environ.get('GEOCODER_API'))
        print(g)

        lng = g.lng
        lat = g.lat

        self.point = Point(lng, lat)
        
        # Call the parent class's save method to actually save the object
        super(Job, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`
```

```
[22/Feb/2023 22:51:32] "POST /admin/jobapp/jo`your text`b/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 160565
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db'
Error transforming geometry from srid '4326' to srid '3857' (OGR failure.)
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db'``
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this error
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = VIRTUAL_ENV_BASE + '\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\geos_c.dll'
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = VIRTUAL_ENV_BASE + '\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal304.dll'

i use / instead of \ in my path